# How can I add a button on Ionic toolbar for all pages?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

In fallowing code I want to add a search Icon at the `navbar` in front of `menu` item:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button icon-only>
    <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

But this code is not working.

Comment: what is not working? what is the error

Comment: It's not showing any button on pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<ion-nav>` first then `<ion-menu>` so it's not covered. And put everything in app.html:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button icon-only>
    <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```